# How to draw a datamaps with an external topoJSON file?

Tags: javascript, topojson

I would like to draw a map with an external topoJSON file. I don't understand why my program isn't working ([gist file](https://gist.github.com/pachevalier/10379191). Does anyone has any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off switching to a different projection, like Mercator or Equirectangular.
AlbersUS is optimized for USA only.

Also there is a typo in your code, there is an extra `{` character, and the `dataUrl` is pointing at the wrong path.

I updated the code, switched projections, and here is what I have:

http://bl.ocks.org/markmarkoh/10900301